# Можно ли создать generic компонент?

Tags: angular2, angular

В общем, сделал generic paginator в виде отдельного класса, который при вызове методов перехода возвращает generic массив.

И вот хочу его сделать в виде отдельного компонента, что бы можно было его многократно использовать на различных компонентах.

Так вот, как вот, можно ли из главного компонента сказать дочернему, что он должен сконструироваться с конкретным типом или нет? Или из дочернего компонента я должен возвращать Any, а родительский класс должен сам к нужному типу все приводить?

Если мой подход в корне не верен, то напишите, как наиболее правильнее это делается.

Comment: нет, нельзя, увы, вы можете указать `<T>` конструкцию, но от нее нет толку

Comment: @overthesanity, т.е получается, что мой пагинатор должен наружу возвращать массив any, а родитель сам рулить преобразованиями?

Comment: дженерики полезны в тех случаях, когда вы явно управляете инициализацией, например `new Array<number>()`, компонент инстанциируется в рантайме причем средствами Angular, поэтому вы не можете перегрузить тип

Comment: есть еще второй вариант, возможно я изложу его в ответе, какая у вас структура компонентов, потому что возможно я не допонимаю вопрос, я просто не понимаю что значит `из дочернего компонента я должен возвращать Any`, что значит возвращать из дочернего компонента?

Comment: Главное компонент, который имеет таблицу, а внизу дочерний компонент- пагинатор. По моей задумке, главный компонент при инициализации должен передать в дочерний компонент список элементов, пагинатор сформировать страницы и родительский компонент должен получить у дочернего список страниц, которые он отображает на странице и отображать их в виде строк в таблице. Вроде, норм или лучше можно?

Comment: я так понимаю что таблиц у вас может быть несколько и все таблицы работают с разными типами сущностей? такой вопрос, а зачем тогда пагинатору знать тип сущности, разве он не должен просто заниматься пагинацией? =D

Comment: @overthesanity я просто привык в C# работать с конкретным типом, а тут это по сути фикция=(.

Comment: ну между TypeScript и C#, увы, совершенно ничего общего (как говорит Хейлсберг и ни в коем случае их нельзя пытаться смешивать), ладно, постараюсь позже дать ответ

Comment: @overthesanity еще такой вопрос, возможно, близкий по теме: Я же родительского компонента внедрить в дочерний какой-нибудь конкретный сервис? Ну например, хочу что бы, когда пагинатор работает в контексте одного родителя то искал по одному, а когда в контексте друго, то по другому. Это через @Input() на сколько я понимаю делается?

Comment: у вас может быть много сущностей, пагинатор должен от них абстрагироваться и ничего о них не знать, родитель-пагинатор должны быть слабо связаны и следовать закону Деметры. В случае с поиском нужно сверху входным параметром передавать функцию-предикат

Comment: @overthesanity а если я хочу извне сказать пагинатору откуда брать данные для пагинации? Например, сделать поле с абстрактным сервисом и из родителя передать какой-то сервис из родительского компонента, который будет дергаться пагинатором, а тот в свою очередь будет возвращать страницы дочернему компоненту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете естественно указать конструкцию `<T>`, но какой от нее толк если вы не можете перегрузить тип:

```
class PaginatorComponent<T> {
  ...
}
```

Универсальные типы полезны в тех случаях когда вы вручную управляете инициализацией, но к сожалению вам не подвластна инициализация компонента. Компонент инстанциируется в рантайме средствами Angular, где нет TypeScript.

Но есть парочка лайфхаков. Для того, чтобы перегрузить тип - вам нужно получить доступ к инстансу компонента. Есть несколько способов, один из них это DOM запрос, используя `@ViewChild`.

Представьте себе такой компонент таблицы:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `
    <app-paginator></app-paginator>
  `
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(PaginatorComponent)
  public paginator: PaginatorComponent<number> = null;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paginator.setData([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }
}
```

Где `PaginatorComponent` это:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paginator',
  template: '<p *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item }}</p>'
})
export class PaginatorComponent<T> {
  public data: T[] = [];

  public setData(data: T[]): void {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Конечно же use кейсы везде разные, в данном случае этот список параграфов - просто банальный пример. Смысл заключается в том, что `PaginatorComponent` должен экспоузить какие-то публичные методы, которые может использовать родительский компонент.

Тем самым логику можно усложнить, например у вас много компонентов таблиц, но вы хотите переиспользовать пагинатор. У каждого компонента таблицы есть свой личный сервис для работы с данными. Пагинатор об этих сервисах в принципе ничего не должен знать. Но эти сервисы должны реализовывать какой-то контракт, например:

```
interface FilteringService<T> {
  filter(data: T[]): T[];
}

export class CarsFilteringService<Car> implements FilteringService<Car> {
  public filter(cars: Car[]): Car[] {
    return cars.filter(/* какой-то предикат */);
  }

  // еще куча бизнес логики внутренней
}

export class BooksFilteringService<Book> implements FilteringService<Book> {
  public filter(books: Book[]): Book[] {
    return books.filter(/* какой-то предикат */);
  }

  // еще куча бизнес логики внутренней
}
```

Это очень грубый пример, но я уверен, что вы разберетесь в этом подходе. `PaginatorComponent` в свою очередь может использовать только интерфейс `FilteringService` и ничего не знать о реальных реализациях, потому что они могут даже не существовать в какой-то момент (например сервис находится в провайдерах модуля, который грузится по требованию):

```
export class PaginatorComponent<T> {
  private data: T[] = [];

  private service: FilteringService<T> | null = null;

  public setData(data: T[]): void {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public setService(service: FilteringService<T>): void {
    this.service = service;
  }

  public filter(): void {
    this.service && this.service.filter(this.data);
  }
}
```

Где в родительском компонента таблицы, имея под рукой уже конкретный инстанс сервиса и имея доступ к инстансу `PaginatorComponent`, вы можете засеттить конкретный сервис:

```
constructor(private booksFilteringService: BooksFilteringService)

this.paginator.setService(this.booksFilteringService);
```

Второй подход - это инстанциирование компонента вручную. Этот подход сложный и требует углубления в само ядро Angular. Для этого используется сервис `ComponentFactoryResolver`, который дает доступ к скомпилированным фабрикам компонентов:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `<ng-container #paginator></ng-container>`
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('paginator', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public paginator: ViewContainerRef = null;

  private ref: ComponentRef<PaginatorComponent<number>> = null;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<PaginatorComponent<number>>(PaginatorComponent);
    this.ref = this.paginator.createComponent<PaginatorComponent<number>>(factory);
    // `ref.instance` - инстанс класса `PaginatorComponent`
    this.ref.instance.setData([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Вместе с `TableComponent` также уничтожаем пагинатор
    this.ref.destroy();
    this.ref = null;
  }
}
```

В этом случае `PaginatorComponent` нужно также добавлять в `entryComponents` модуля, для всех компонентов объявленных `entryComponents` модуля компилятор генерирует фабрику (`ComponentFactory<T>`) и кеширует в `ComponentFactoryResolver`. У каждого модуля есть свой `ComponentFactoryResolver`.